# Working with UTF-8 charset in php

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I have been struggling with the UTF-8 charset for quite a while now, and I am still confused about some things.

I have a web page which allow clients to create HTML files and directories on server. The directory name can be in any language. *Adiós, días, chapter, level* etc. The directories created are later on used as a URL for the HTML files created. Let’s say the user created a directory `Adiós` and then a file called `welcome.html`. To view this  file, the client clicks a link and for that I get the directory and file name to create a path `Adiós/welcome.html`. Now I am confused about these things.

1. When making the directory in php, should I `urlencode()` every file and directory name?
2. If I do `urlencode` the directory name, will the browser be able to open my HTML page? Instead of `href="Adiós/welcome.html"` it will be `href="Adi%C3%B3s/welcome.html"`.
3. There’s sometimes an image on my web page which I will src as `"Adi%C3%B3s/ing.jpg"`; is this going to work?
4. Should the url in address bar show non‐ASCII characters?

I actually `urlencode()`d everything but ran into issues as described in point 2 and 3, so I wanted to know what the right approach is for directory naming when working with languages other than English!

Comment: Have you thought of having your user's use only english characters rather then urlencode()? It just means that folders and files will be easier to read and access

Comment: naa...its a req that the folder names can be in any language

Comment: **This has nothing to do with the language,** and certainly has nothing to do with whether it is English or non‐English! All it has to do with ASCII and non‐ASCII.  Do not conflate English with ASCII: this is an error.  English uses non‐ASCII, and many non‐English languages use ASCII.  Say what you mean, damn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save the names urlencoded in the filesystem, you must double urlencode the links and image sources if you want to access them directly, bypassing PHP. Alternatively, you could save the names without any kind of urlencoding, in which case the links would need one pass. However, this last option isn't available on Windows, where Unicode is not supported in the filesystem functions.

Alternatively, if you still want to bypass PHP, you can use rewrite rules to reencode the names once they have urldecoded by Apache.

Finally, you should take note that your approach is dangerous -- difficult to get right without security implications. You should consider have a single PHP file serving your pages and saving them in a database. You could still keep pretty filenames by using the PATH_INFO variable. You could also add a caching layer in front of PHP if performance becomes an issue with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. That depends on the underlying OS (IMHO Linux is capable of handling UTF-8 filenames, Windows is not)
2. normally a browser should simply request and open files like `/tülüvkrü.htm`, I don't how MS IE handles such things;
3. [same as second]
4. sure, if the filename does contain them; as stated for 2. and 3., this depends on the used browser;

Example: http://tülüvkrü.de/中华人民共和国.htm (should display "It works!")

Comment: @Andrew Moore: Unicode is not a serialization scheme. Therefore it is impossible to store things “in Unicode”. This is an error in the documentation. What does it *really* mean?

Comment: @tchrist: It means that the filenames are encoded in UTF-8 when stored in the MFT. As simple as that. The filesystem in Windows XP and up is completely in UTF-8. Software developed in Windows however much make sure to called the wide-char version of each API function however (`GetLongPathNameW` versus `GetLongPathNameA` for example).

Comment: @Andrew Irrelevant, as PHP uses the ANSI versions of the Win32 API, thereby being able to open only files composed of characters available in the active codepage.

Comment: @Andrew Those are not "ambiguous" versions. Those are macros that expand to either one of the versions depending on whether you have UNICODE defined (which PHP doesn't). PHP is in fact *not* able to open an arbitrary path on Windows (try it -- create a filename using a script not supported by your codepage and try to open it with PHP). And no, you can't just pass UTF-16 data (which \0 bytes in the middle...) to PHP's file functions, the Windows API doesn't  "autodetect" the encoding passed (which is impossible BTW) and adjust the code path accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

> I have a web page which allow clients to create html files and folders on server.

That's wrong idea.
Store their files in the database and emulate directory structure as well.

EDIT
because of these silly accusations in the comments I have to clarify:

## I am talking of this very case of HTML files with fancy names in particular, not of binary files in general.

satisfied?

Comment: well there are only two peoples that are allowed to create folders...not the general public!!...still wrong?

Comment: yes. no webmaster in the world have an idea of creating physical folders for store user-supplied pages.

Comment: Many hosting-providers are allowing that via the customer-backends.

Comment: -1 - storing files in a database is the wrong thing to do, all you're doing is filling your database engine's valuable cache memory with large binary objects which is highly wasteful. Use the file system for the actual files but use the database to store metadata and pointers to where the files are really stored (which can be abstracted away and does not necessarily need to be an actual hierarchy of user folders). In fact the files could be stored in a separate  cookieless domain much like Stack Overflow's http://cdn.sstatic.net.

Comment: @Kev them aren't binary, dude. It's HTML.

Comment: Files is files, whether binary or not.

Comment: I'm not discussing the question, I'm addressing the wrong advice given in your answer. Filling your database engine's cache with opaque non-queryable data such as binary data or big blobs of HTML is wasteful.

Comment: in fact, every site is storing HTML pages in the database. I bet even SO does it. there is noting wrong with storing HTML in database.